# Conversion issue in the simple selection with computed column - Strange Behaviour Facing Firsttime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, type-conversion

There isn't any issue while inserting the record in the table, which has one computed column but in the simple selection, I am getting conversion issue. I am facing this issue first time so strange for me. Can please anyone help me on this with the detail information about this behavior :

```
CREATE TABLE #employee(
    userId INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
    userLogin AS ('HR'+userId), 
    firstName VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #employee(firstName)
SELECT 'Lord'

SELECT * FROM #employee
```

Sorry, using CONCAT there isn't any issue, if I use as CONCAT('HR',userId). What was the cause of issue in the above concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get this problem if you simply do:

```
userLogin AS ('HR' + 1)
```

The "problem" is that `+` can mean either numeric addition or string concatenation.  Because there is a number as an operand, SQL Server interprets the operation as addition, so it tries to convert `'HR'` to a number.  Hence the error.

I think you know that:

```
userLogin as (concat('HR', userid))
```

should fix the problem.  Or, you can explicitly convert the user id to a string:

```
userLogin as ('HR' + cast(userid as varchar(10)))
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, there I can't use CONCAT in SQL SERVER-2008, any solution ?

Comment: Sir, Can we do it in the selection time, I have tried CONVERT & CAST but not succeed. I tried to alter column due to huge data it's freezing so please suggest me if we have any way ?

Comment: @Suraz . . . A computed column should not be stored in a table, unless it is marked as `persisted`.  Try adding a new computed column that is not persisted.  That should be fast.